# Issue using executeQueryLocally without server metadata

Tags: breeze

I'm not using EF, so have followed the NoDb sample to successfully load data from my WebApi without using the server side metadata. After the initial load, I was hoping to use the local data cache in the EntityManager while the user interacts with the page. The problem is when I call executeQueryLocally, the cached data set is empty. I stepped through the code to see why the data wasn't being saved to the cache, and there were two issues:

1. in _getEntityType, metadataStore.isEmpty() was returning true.
2. in _getEntityType, metadataStore._getEntityTypeNameForResourceName was returning nothing

To get around the this, I added calls in my code to metadataStore.addDataService and metadataStore._setEntityTypeForResourceName. After adding these, the cache was saved properly and executeQueryLocally worked. I'm assuming this was not the intended way to get this to work... Is there something else I am doing wrong? Or is this a bug that can be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for taking so long getting back to this one.

We just made the metadataStore.setEntityTypeForResourceName public in breeze v.1.1.3.  ( we renamed the method to remove the first '_".

Otherwise, you did exactly the right thing.  Good catch.